# Given $y'=y^4$, is there any $y(a)=b$ which makes the problem unsolvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I can't figure out how to find out if any $a$ and $b$ makes the initial value problem unsolvable.

$y'=y^4$

My general solution is as followed:

$$y(x)=-\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{3(x+C)}}$$

Comment: What do you mean by unsolvable? According to [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem), there is always a local solution as $y \mapsto y^4$ is locally Lipschitz.

Comment: Now plug in $y(x_0)=y_0$ and see if can you always solve for $C$.

Comment: You're general solution is correct. You can usuallly then solve $y(a)=b$ except when...

Comment: @Alan Always? I don't think that is quite right.

Comment: @coffeemath $y=0$ is a solution as well.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews the apparent problem isn't real, you'll never hit the division by 0 because $b$ is a real number

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Alan only said "see *if* you can always solve for C,"

Comment: I don't need to find a solution, I need to find values of a and b which makes the initial value problem unsolvable

Comment: @a.brei Again, can you explain what you mean by unsolvable? There **always** exists a local solution, even if it means the always vanishing map. I requested your question to be closed as it is unclear as it is.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net well isn't that the answer then. I didn't say "what is" I said "is there". So the answer is no, there is not any values which makes the initial value problem unsolvable, because there is always a solution.

Comment: @a.brei I provided an answer. However, I suggest that you edit the question as the title and the first sentence of the body of the question seem in contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

**The answer (to the question in the title) is negative**

As the map $y \mapsto y^4$ is locally Lipschitz, there is always locally a solution according to [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem).

If $b = 0$, then the always vanishing map is the solution.